# Issue with flexbox in CSS, flex items refuse to have an equal sized width while centered

Tags: css, flexbox

I can't make my flex items be of equal size in a flex container that is at the center of the page. It seems simple, but i keep trying codes that are supposed to work and they keep acting up and i ve started to get quite frustrated. For more specifications, i upload a screenshot of my code.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcpK9.png)

This code refers to a flex div container that consists of 3 divs that serve as flex items, which include text of different number of words. I want them to stay at the center as 3 columns of equal width, however, they currently get spread out according to how much words each item has (for example, the 1st column is taking up half the page). No matter what code i write that affects the width, it messes up the positioning, for example, i tried to enter width: 500px; at the end of the code above, and the items moved from the center to the left part of the page. Can you please give me a piece of code that solves this problem, and if possible, explain to me the reason? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide code examples (HTML, CSS) in Code snippet?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try This ->

```
.container { display: flex; }
.container > * { flex: 1; }
```

When we do `flex: 1` which is basically a short hand for flex-grow ,flex-shrink and flex-basis, makes  flex-shrink value 1 and the flex-basis value 0. (so all child elements have the same starting point), and then we allow them to grow by 1.

Comment: Please add some explanation. Code-only answers may actually solve the problem but they are generally hard for actually understanding and learning how things work.